Is it possible to use Wallet connect with "self-hosted safe infrastructure(safe-wallet-web)"
What I wanna use


When I use safe app(https://app.safe.global/) then, i can connect dapp with wallet-connect
But When I use self-hosted safe infrastructure(https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/tree/main)
There is no button(or feature) like above.


currently I tested it in the ethereum network, but I will use safe-infra with unsupported network.

Try to do
I added "NEXT_PUBLIC_WC_PROJECT_ID=XXX" in the ui.env file

ref from https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/blob/dev/README.md?plain=1#L32

but It only activate the button below

Question
Q1. What should I do now if I want to use a specific dapp (swap, lending... etc) on a network that is not officially supported by the safe global app?
Q2. For the above question, I have tried to connect to the dapp through "wallet connect" like a safe global app, but those features are not visible in the safe-infrastructure repository. What should I do?

Thanks for your good question.
Could you try setting the NATIVE_WALLETCONNECT flag in your config service?
If this works, please mark your question as answered. I am happy to support via comments if you encounter further issues.

https://github.com/search?q=org%3Asafe-global%20NATIVE_WALLETCONNECT&type=code
I think there is no related keyword...
